# MySQL REPLACE function not work when the text gets long

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress

I have a table *(actually generated by WordPress)*. I want to replace some text using `REPLACE` function, but it does not work.

Text in the field:

`<!-- wp:blocks/amazon-product {"url":"https://www.amazon.com/OutdoorMaster-OTG-Ski-Goggles-Protection/dp/B01HLV5HR6","category":"1","headline":"OutdoorMaster OTG Ski Goggles - Over Glasses Ski/Snowboard Goggles for Men, Women \u0026 Youth - 100% UV Protection (Black Frame + VLT 10% Grey Lens with REVO Silver)","price":"$17.99","review":"",","checkPrice":"Buy Now on Amazon","isUrlPresent":true,"cacheDate":"2020-04-05T07:27:27.875Z"} /-->`

And this text is exactly copied from the field, I tried to do this:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
  SET post_content =
  REPLACE(
    post_content,
    'the above text',
    'some new text'
  )
  WHERE ID = 1;
```

and no row affected, but when I lessen the text let say I do for `<!-- wp:blocks/amazon-product {"url":"https://www.amazon.com/OutdoorMaster-OTG-Ski-Goggles-Protection/dp/B01HLV5HR6"` only, then the text gets replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As You can see

> ```
> Set @a = 'a<!-- wp:blocks/amazon-product {"url":"https://www.amazon.com/OutdoorMaster-OTG-Ski-Goggles-Protection/dp/B01HLV5HR6","category":"1","headline":"OutdoorMaster OTG Ski Goggles - Over Glasses Ski/Snowboard Goggles for Men, Women \u0026 Youth - 100% UV Protection (Black Frame + VLT 10% Grey Lens with REVO Silver)","price":"$17.99","review":"",","checkPrice":"Buy Now on Amazon","isUrlPresent":true,"cacheDate":"2020-04-05T07:27:27.875Z"} /-->"a'
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT REPLACE (@a,'<!-- wp:blocks/amazon-product {"url":"https://www.amazon.com/OutdoorMaster-OTG-Ski-Goggles-Protection/dp/B01HLV5HR6","category":"1","headline":"OutdoorMaster OTG Ski Goggles - Over Glasses Ski/Snowboard Goggles for Men, Women \u0026 Youth - 100% UV Protection (Black Frame + VLT 10% Grey Lens with REVO Silver)","price":"$17.99","review":"",","checkPrice":"Buy Now on Amazon","isUrlPresent":true,"cacheDate":"2020-04-05T07:27:27.875Z"} /-->','test')
> ```
>
> ```
> | REPLACE (@a,'<!-- wp:blocks/amazon-product {"url":"https://www.amazon.com/OutdoorMaster-OTG-Ski-Goggles-Protection/dp/B01HLV5HR6","category":"1","headline":"OutdoorMaster OTG Ski Goggles - Over Glasses Ski/Snowboard Goggles for Men, Women \u0026 Youth - 1 |
> | :-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | atest"a                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=facf07b60e823d3a5193dbe18a43a7e1)*

The problem is not the size of your text.

You must try first

```
SELECT post_content FROM wp_posts WHERE post_content LIKE '%your text%';
```

Ans see if it has any result.

Comment: no i didn't get any result using `SELECT`. What do i do now?

Comment: That is the cause for your problem as i said.. Depending on the mysql version you can use other methods REG_REPLACE.... Try minimize the change so  that it can find your pattern better.  In most cases such massive Replace take a lot of experimentation and multiple test, so try to create a representatove sample and try to find a godd replace strategy

Comment: I have mysql 5.7

Comment: I am not getting what is the exact reason why it's not working on myside, i tried to change the version on the fiddle to 5.7 and it is working, but when I put query then it doesn't work.

Comment: That hgas nothing to do with the Version Replace only finds the **exact** wordingWhen the select shows nothing you have no such data in your column.